# Is React based website is search engine friendly

Tags: seo, content, dynamic, react-js

I'm asking question because most of the content will be loading in dynamically created html.

I'm planning to develop an online store (a very small project) I'm planning to use React for the first time for this kind of project.

I want to know does these dynamic pages are search engine friendly? or if there are some techniques to keep pages search engine friendly.

Is it helpful to put something sitemap.xml or other xml to guide search engine regarding content.

Comment: Related: [Do search engines perform JS rendering while crawling?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/140252)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know does these dynamic pages are search engine friendly?

Very few technologies are inherently search engine friendly or unfriendly. Google can parse and render JavaScript. However, using JavaScript opens up a ton of potential SEO-problems that can be very hard to identify and fix.

> or if there are some techniques to keep pages search engine friendly.

There is. Prerendering or server-side rendering allow you to develop your site in JavaScript but server pure HTML pages to Google. You could look into a solution like [Preact](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/cli/pre-rendering/) to enable this for your React website.

> Is it helpful to put something sitemap.xml or other xml to guide
> search engine regarding content.

An XML sitemap can help Google find all your pages. This is especially important if your navigation (internal linking) is JavaScript-based on Google has problems understanding it.

But an XML sitemap will not solve rendering issues that prevent Google from seeing, crawling, and indexing your content.

My suggestion it to read the [Google guide on JavaScript SEO](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/javascript/javascript-seo-basics). The content is good. But please keep in mind Google sometimes says that something is not an issue when most SEOs will tell you that it infact is an issue. Therefore you should also read the [JavaScript SEO guide from Onely](https://www.onely.com/blog/ultimate-guide-javascript-seo/).