# How can a react/vue apps like these rank just by using client side rendering?

Tags: google, googlebot, web-crawlers

By client-side rendering I mean, you can't see any content (h1,title,meta tags etc) in the source code, which is the only place where google bot can learn what a page is about.

here is this site: `https://pinterestdownloder.video/ideapindownloader`.

It is ranking in the top 5 of Google. This is my website, and I just wanted to know how it is possible for the Google bot to see and rank with server-side rendering.

Comment: Related: [Do search engines perform JS rendering while crawling?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/140250/do-search-engines-perform-js-rendering-while-crawling)

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do client-side rendering is to use javascript.  And Google will execute javascript.  Even when one of my sites was one giant PWA (Progressive Web App) written entirely in javascript, Google managed to index its.

> **Understand the JavaScript SEO basics**
>
> Do you suspect that JavaScript issues might be blocking your page or some of your content from showing up in Google Search? Learn how to fix JavaScript-related problems with our troubleshooting guide.
>
> JavaScript is an important part of the web platform because it provides many features that turn the web into a powerful application platform. Making your JavaScript-powered web applications discoverable via Google Search can help you find new users and re-engage existing users as they search for the content your web app provides. While Google Search runs JavaScript with an evergreen version of Chromium, there are a few things that you can optimize.

From [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/javascript/javascript-seo-basics)